# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

I'm a new flutter user, so this time I'm having problems when I want to update the data can't be sent to the database and an error message appears like this

> I/flutter ( 6939): {body1:d, body2:d, body3:d, body4:c, body5:c}
> E/flutter ( 6939): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)]
> Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is
> not a subtype of type 'String' E/flutter ( 6939): #0
> Network.updateData (package:flutter_auth/network/api.dart:41:26)
> E/flutter ( 6939): #1 _EditCustomerState._update
> (package:flutter_auth/screens/Menu/edit_customer.dart:217:31)
> E/flutter ( 6939): #2 _EditCustomerState.build.
> (package:flutter_auth/screens/Menu/edit_customer.dart:167:29)

How do you think the solution to overcome so that the data can be updated and stored in the database how?

Here I give a snippet of my source code
**edit_nasabah.dart**

```
class EditNasabah extends StatefulWidget {
  Nasabah nasabah;
  EditNasabah({this.nasabah});
  @override
  _EditNasabahState createState() => _EditNasabahState(this.nasabah);
}

class _EditNasabahState extends State<EditNasabah> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final Nasabah nasabah;
  _EditNasabahState(this.nasabah);
  bool _secureText = true;
  final TextEditingController _nama_debiturController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _alamatController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _no_telpController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _no_ktpController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _no_selularController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nama_debiturController.text = "";
    _alamatController.text = "";
    _no_telpController.text = "";
    _no_ktpController.text = "";
    _no_selularController.text = "";
  }

  showHide() {
    setState(() {
      _secureText = !_secureText;
    });
  }

  _showMsg(msg) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(msg),
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Edit Data"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Card(
                child: Column(

                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.info, size: 50),
                      title: Text('Edit Form Debitur'),
                      subtitle: Text('Silahkan edit sesuai form dibawah ini'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _nama_debiturController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Nama Debitur',
                      ),
                      validator: (nameValue) {
                        if (nameValue.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your full name';
                        }
                        nasabah.nama_debitur = nameValue;
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _alamatController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Alamat',
                      ),
                      validator: (alamatValue) {
                        if (alamatValue.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your full name';
                        }
                        nasabah.alamat = alamatValue;
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _no_telpController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Nomor Telepon',
                      ),
                      validator: (notlpValue) {
                        if (notlpValue.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your full name';
                        }
                        nasabah.no_telp = notlpValue;
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _no_ktpController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'NIK',
                      ),
                      validator: (noktpValue) {
                        if (noktpValue.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your full name';
                        }
                        nasabah.no_ktp = noktpValue;
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _no_selularController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'No Selular',
                      ),
                      validator: (nosllValue) {
                        if (nosllValue.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your full name';
                        }
                        nasabah.no_selular = nosllValue;
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            _update();
                          }
                        },
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                        child: Ink(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                colors: [Color(0xff374ABE), Color(0xff64B6FF)],
                                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                          child: Container(
                            constraints:
                            BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100.0, minHeight: 50.0),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              _isLoading? 'Proccessing..' : 'Simpan',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

**For the update function as follows**

```
void _update() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    Map<String, String> data = {
      "body1" : _nama_debiturController.text,
      "body2": _alamatController.text,
      "body3": _no_telpController.text,
      "body4" : _no_ktpController.text,
      "body5" : _no_selularController.text
    };
    print(data);

    var res = await Network().updateData(data, 'mstdebitur');
    var body = json.decode(res.body);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      localStorage.setString('mstdebitur', json.encode(body['mstdebitur']));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Berhasil Disimpan'),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      ));

    } else {
      if (body['message']['nama_debitur'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['nama_debitur'][0].toString());
      } else if (body['message']['alamat'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['alamat'][0].toString());
      } else if (body['message']['no_telp'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['no_telp'][0].toString());
      }
      else if (body['message']['no_ktp'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['no_ktp'][0].toString());
      }
      else if (body['message']['no_selular'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['no_selular'][0].toString());
      }
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: Text("Gagal")));
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

**api.dart**

```
updateData(apiURL, id) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiURL + '/' + id.toString();
    await _getToken();
    return await http.put(
      fullUrl,
      headers: _setHeaders(),
    );
  }
```

**nasabah_service.dart**

```
static Future<List<Nasabah>> updateUser(id) async {
    final response = await Network().updateData(baseUrl, id);
    List<Nasabah> list = parseResponse(response.body);
    return list;
  }
```

I ask for help to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: You are calling updateData with a Map, but attempting to use it as a string.

Comment: can you help me to modify my source code ?

Comment: With what is provided I'm not sure what to change it to. Is there another method in Network that you should be using the map in instead of updateData?

Comment: for other methods are free, can you help me ? so that the data can be updated and stored in the database?

Comment: I believe what you are missing is a body on your put.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what your server API looks like, I'm going to make a best-effort guess. Feel free to comment if there are follow-up questions.

Add a body parameter to your `updateData`:

```
updateData(apiURL, id, body) async {
  var fullUrl = _url + apiURL + '/' + id.toString();
  await _getToken();
  return await http.put(
    fullUrl,
    headers: _setHeaders(),
    body: json.encode(body),
  );
}
```

Then pass the constructed map in your `_update`:

```
Map<String, String> data = {
  "body1" : _nama_debiturController.text,
  "body2": _alamatController.text,
  "body3": _no_telpController.text,
  "body4" : _no_ktpController.text,
  "body5" : _no_selularController.text
};
var res = await Network().updateData(baseUrl, 'mstdebitur', data);
```

Comment: The error has been resolved, but the data cannot be saved to the database, here is an example video of the data update https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38ZoHWsJ47k

Comment: If the server is not saving, then there is something missing in the implementation for the PUT. If your app is not updating, it is not fetching the new data from the server when you navigate back or you are not updating local state.